# Rotating 1D numpy array of radial intensities into 2D array of spacial intensities

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, rotation

I have a numpy array filled with intensity readings at different radii in a uniform circle (for context, this is a 1D radiative transfer project for protostellar formation models: while much better models exist, my supervisor wasnts me to have the experience of producing one so I understand how others work).

I want to take that 1d array, and "rotate" it through a circle, forming a 2D array of intensities that could then be shown with imshow (or, with a bit of work, aplpy). The final array needs to be 2d, and the projection needs to be Cartesian, not polar.

I can do it with nested for loops, and I can do it with lookup tables, but I have a feeling there must be a neat way of doing it in numpy or something.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I have had to go back and recreate my (frankly horrible) mess of for loops and if statements that I had before. If I really tried, I could probably get rid of one of the loops and one of the if statements by condensing things down. However, the aim is not to make it work with for loops, but see if there is a built in way to rotate the array.
impB is an array that differs slightly from what I stated it was before. Its actually just a list of radii where particles are detected. I then bin those into radius bins to get the intensity (or frequency if you prefer) in each radius. R is the scale factor for my radius as I run the model in a dimensionless way. iRes is a resolution scale factor, essentially how often I want to sample my radial bins. Everything else should be clear.

```
radJ = np.ndarray(shape=(2*iRes, 2*iRes))    # Create array of 2xRadius square

for i in range(iRes):
    n = len(impB[np.where(impB[:] < ((i+1.) * (R / iRes)))])    # Count number of things within this radius +1
    m = len(impB[np.where(impB[:] <= ((i) * (R / iRes)))])      # Count number of things in this radius
    a = (((i + 1) * (R / iRes))**2 - ((i) * (R / iRes))**2) * math.pi    # A normalisation factor based on area.....dont ask
    for x in range(iRes):
        for y in range(iRes):
            if (x**2 + y**2) < (i * iRes)**2:
                if (x**2 + y**2) >= (i * iRes)**2:    # Checks for radius, and puts in cartesian space
                    radJ[x+iRes,y+iRes] = (n-m) / a    # Put in actual intensity bins
                    radJ[x+iRes,-y+iRes] = (n-m) / a
                    radJ[-x+iRes,y+iRes] = (n-m) / a
                    radJ[-x+iRes,-y+iRes] = (n-m) / a
```

Comment: Share you loopy code, if you have implemented it?

Comment: I just updated my code with a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Nested loops are a simple approach for that. With `ri_data_r` and `y` containing your radius values (difference to the middle pixel) and the array for rotation, respectively, I would suggest:

```
from scipy import interpolate
import numpy as np
y = np.random.rand(100)
ri_data_r = np.linspace(-len(y)/2,len(y)/2,len(y))
interpol_index = interpolate.interp1d(ri_data_r, y)
xv = np.arange(-1, 1, 0.01) # adjust your matrix values here
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xv, xv)
profilegrid = np.ones(X.shape, float)
for i, x in enumerate(X[0, :]):
    for k, y in enumerate(Y[:, 0]):
        current_radius = np.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2)
        profilegrid[i, k] = interpol_index(current_radius)
print(profilegrid)
```

This will give you exactly what you are looking for. You just have to take in your array and calculate an symmetric array `ri_data_r` that has the same length as your data array and contains the distance between the actual data and the middle of the array. The code is doing this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question in a different context and I hope I understood it right. Here are two other ways of doing this. The first uses [skimage.transform.warp](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.warp) with interpolation of desired order (here we use order=0 Nearest-neighbor). This method is slower but more precise and needs less memory then the second method.

The second one does not use interpolation, therefore is faster but also less precise and needs way more memory because it stores each 2D array containing one tilt until the end, where they are averaged with `np.nanmean()`.

The difference between both solutions stemmed from the problem of handling the center of the final image where the tilts overlap the most, i.e. the first one would just add values with each tilt ending up out of the original range. This was "solved" by clipping the matrix in each step to a `global_min` and `global_max` (consult the code). The second one solves it by taking the mean of the tilts where they overlap, which forces us to use the `np.nan`.

Please, read the *Example of usage* and *Sanity check* sections in order to understand the plot titles.

### Solution 1:

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import warp

def rotate_vector(vector, deg_angle):
    # Credit goes to skimage.transform.radon
    assert vector.ndim == 1, 'Pass only 1D vectors, e.g. use array.ravel()'
    center = vector.size // 2
    square = np.zeros((vector.size, vector.size))
    square[center,:] = vector
    rad_angle = np.deg2rad(deg_angle)
    cos_a, sin_a = np.cos(rad_angle), np.sin(rad_angle)
    R = np.array([[cos_a, sin_a, -center * (cos_a + sin_a - 1)],
                  [-sin_a, cos_a, -center * (cos_a - sin_a - 1)],
                  [0, 0, 1]])
    # Approx. 80% of time is spent in this function
    return warp(square, R, clip=False, output_shape=((vector.size, vector.size)))

def place_vectors(vectors, deg_angles):
    matrix = np.zeros((vectors.shape[-1], vectors.shape[-1]))
    global_min, global_max = 0, 0
    for i, deg_angle in enumerate(deg_angles):
        tilt = rotate_vector(vectors[i], deg_angle)
        global_min = tilt.min() if global_min > tilt.min() else global_min
        global_max = tilt.max() if global_max < tilt.max() else global_max
        matrix += tilt
        matrix = np.clip(matrix, global_min, global_max)
    return matrix
```

[image: Solution 1: Visualization of outputs]

### Solution 2:

Credit for the idea goes to my colleague Michael Scherbela.

```
import numpy as np

def rotate_vector(vector, deg_angle):
    assert vector.ndim == 1, 'Pass only 1D vectors, e.g. use array.ravel()'
    square = np.ones([vector.size, vector.size]) * np.nan
    radius = vector.size // 2
    r_values = np.linspace(-radius, radius, vector.size)
    rad_angle = np.deg2rad(deg_angle)
    ind_x = np.round(np.cos(rad_angle) * r_values + vector.size/2).astype(np.int)
    ind_y = np.round(np.sin(rad_angle) * r_values + vector.size/2).astype(np.int)
    ind_x = np.clip(ind_x, 0, vector.size-1)
    ind_y = np.clip(ind_y, 0, vector.size-1)
    square[ind_y, ind_x] = vector
    return square

def place_vectors(vectors, deg_angles):
    matrices = []
    for deg_angle, vector in zip(deg_angles, vectors):
        matrices.append(rotate_vector(vector, deg_angle))
    matrix = np.nanmean(np.array(matrices), axis=0)
    return np.nan_to_num(matrix, copy=False, nan=0.0)
```

[image: Solution 2: Visualization of outputs]

### Example of usage:

```
r = 100  # Radius of the circle, i.e. half the length of the vector
n = int(np.pi * r / 8)  # Number of vectors, e.g. number of tilts in tomography
v = np.ones(2*r)  # One vector, e.g. one tilt in tomography
V = np.array([v]*n)  # All vectors, e.g. a sinogram in tomography

# Rotate 1D vector to a specific angle (output is 2D)
angle = 45
rotated = rotate_vector(v, angle) 

# Rotate each row of a 2D array according to its angle (output is 2D)
angles = np.linspace(-90, 90, num=n, endpoint=False)
inplace = place_vectors(V, angles)
```

### Sanity check:

These are just simple checks which by no means cover all possible edge cases. Depending on your use case you might want to extend the checks and adjust the method.

```
# I. Sanity check
# Assuming n <= πr and v = np.ones(2r)
# Then sum(inplace) should be approx. equal to (n * (2πr - n)) / π 
# which is an area that should be covered by the tilts

desired_area = (n * (2 * np.pi * r - n)) / np.pi
covered_area = np.sum(inplace)
covered_frac = covered_area / desired_area
print(f'This method covered {covered_frac * 100:.2f}% '
      'of the area which should be covered in total.')

# II. Sanity check
# Assuming n <= πr and v = np.ones(2r)
# Then a circle M with radius m <= r should be the largest circle which
# is fully covered by the vectors. I.e. its mean should be no less than 1.
# If n = πr then m = r. 
# m = n / π

m = int(n / np.pi)
# Code for circular mask not included
mask = create_circular_mask(2*r, 2*r, center=None, radius=m) 
m_area = np.mean(inplace[mask])
print(f'Full radius r={r}, radius m={m}, mean(M)={m_area:.4f}.')
```

### Code for plotting:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))
plt.subplot(121)
rotated = np.nan_to_num(rotated)  # not necessary in case of the first method
plt.title(
    f'Output of rotate_vector(), angle={angle}°\n'
    f'Sum is {np.sum(rotated):.2f} and should be {np.sum(v):.2f}')
plt.imshow(rotated, cmap=plt.cm.Greys_r)

plt.subplot(122)
plt.title(
    f'Output of place_vectors(), r={r}, n={n}\n'
    f'Covered {covered_frac * 100:.2f}% of the area which should be covered.\n'
    f'Mean of the circle M is {m_area:.4f} and should be 1.0.')
plt.imshow(inplace)
circle=plt.Circle((r, r), m, color='r', fill=False)
plt.gcf().gca().add_artist(circle)
plt.gcf().gca().legend([circle], [f'Circle M (m={m})'])
```